# Persist SSH Command

Tags: shell-script, shell, ssh

First off, I know about `tmux` and `screen`. My conundrum: I started a shell script over SSH expecting it would take a short amount of time, so I left my computer on overnight.

I can't terminate and restart the shell command, otherwise it will restart from the beginning. I would like to terminate my SSH connection without terminating the shell script. Is there anything I can do retroactively (i.e. command is already running in SSH terminal) that will detach it and allow me to safely disconnect my computer?

Comment: You just need to use ‘bg and fg’ that’s it

Comment: And tough luck if SIGHUP (or systemd, despite `nohup` kills it anyway).

Comment: @JaredNielsen there's `reptyr` which should allow you to move it to another tty, but frankly I haven't used it (I've only used some similar hack done by myself). But I guess you're not into experimenting, so you better leave your computer connected & running now ;_)

Comment: you can also `disown` the process - but you can't (easily) get it back.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if `detach` might work?  Usually if you do that on the existing terminal session, you can then exit that shell and the process you have 'detached' will continue to run.  You will still need to have suspended and backgrounded that process first.  The effect is as if you had used the `nohup` command.

However I note that some responses indicate `systemd` may still kill your process -- I have not seen that to date myself so be aware.

EDIT:
***DUH*** for 'detach' read `disown` at least on CentOS and cousins. My apologies to anyone I misled.  Although I do recall a 'detach' command from somewhere ...

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is pause the job with `CTRL+Z`. Then have it continue as a foreground job with the `fg` command or a background job with the `bg` command. Based on your question, you are going to want the `bg` command. Afterwards, you can confirm whether or not it worked with the `jobs` command BEFORE you exit out of the session. And just as a warning, after exiting out the session, you will have no way to track when or if the script finished (other than by whatever operation the script may execute). So just as a recap:

```
CTRL+Z
$ jobs
$ bg
$ jobs
$ exit
```

As another disclaimer: No one but the person working on your system can know if the environment you have set up will allow you to disconnect and allow the command to continue running in the background. It should work on most setups, but you never know. If possible, I would test it on a test script to see if you can stop and restart it

Comment: beware that `systemd` may still kill your background jobs -- even if they survive the tty teardown.